# How to concat rows based on ID,

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

Using standard SQL in bigquery:

Given a table such as: Where the values have been counted so only appear once

```
| id | key | value |
--------------------
| 1 | read |  aa   |
| 1 | read |  bb   |
| 1 | name |  abc  |
| 2 | read |  bb   |
| 2 | read |  cc   |
| 2 | name |  def  |
| 2 | value|  some |
| 3 | read |  aa   |
```

How can I make it so each row is one user and their respective values? e.g. NEST

So the table would look like:

```
| id | key | value |
--------------------
| 1 | read |  aa   |
|   | read |  bb   |
|   | name |  abc  |
| 2 | read |  bb   |
|   | read |  cc   |
|   | name |  def  |
|   | value|  some |
| 3 | read |  aa   |
```

I've tried using `ARRAY_AGG` on the column, which ends up listing all the values of that column.

I just need to have each row as a single user with multiple values, as shown above.

Like BigQuery does here, this is what I want it to look like:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Below is for BigQuery Standard SQL

```
#standardSQL
SELECT id, ARRAY_AGG(STRUCT(key AS key, value AS value)) params
FROM `project.dataset.table`
GROUP BY id
```

if to apply to your sample data  - result is

[image]

Comment: Hero you've helped me again, didn't realise I had to combine it with STRUCT, makes sense after reading docs. I've been spending the last week trying to learn Standard SQL, i'm a backend dev and will soon be moving teams where i'll need it. Is there any resources you can suggest?

Comment: I think, BQ doc is quite good. keep reading, experimenting and asking here when stuck with something :o)